# Find regular expression of length specified and starting and ending also specified in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want to find all the words of length 3 with starting with 'l' and ending with 'f'.
Here's my code:

```
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("\\bl.+?f{3}\\b");
Matcher mt = pt.matcher("#Java life! Go ahead Java,lyf,fly,luf,loof");

while(mt.find()) {
    System.out.println(mt.group());
}
```

It's showing nothing. tried out this also `Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("l.+?f{3}");` still not getting expected o/p.

The o/p should be:

> lyf luf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you need is

```
\bl\wf\b
```

Explanation:

Since your word must be three character long, that means there can only be one letter between l and f, so that's why I didn't put a quantifier there.

Your regex is wrong because

- `f{3}` means 3 f's, not 3 character long in total
- `.` matches everything, including non word characters. Use `\w` instead.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the purpose of \w? Your answer was pretty helpful though.

Comment: @AndrewWatson Match any word character i.e. `0-9a-zA-Z_`. You can also use `[a-zA-Z]` in place of `\w` if you want only letters.

Comment: so in your code l\wf means start with l and end with f right?

Comment: Yes, and with one word character in between them. @AndrewWatson

Answer (score 3):

You can use a word boundary `\b`, then match for `l`, a word character `\w` and then `f` ending with a word boundary `\b`.

[`\bl\wf\b`](https://regex101.com/r/DvyVRf/1)

**Explanation**

- Match a word boundary `\b`
- Match `l`
- Match a word character `\w` (\w is a shorthand character, matches the ASCII characters [A-Za-z0-9_])
- Match a `f`
- Match a word boundary `\b`

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/rJgZwOzMG)

Comment: Can you please tell me the purpose of \w?

Comment: @AndrewWatson `\w` matches a [word character](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html)